# Postgres ERROR: cannot cast type double precision to date

Tags: postgresql, casting, precision

I have a table with creation timestamps as decimals and am trying to convert to date data type. When I go to cast as date I get the following error message: "ERROR: cannot cast type double precision to date". [[image: column example]]

```
cast(creation_timestamp as date)
```

Comment: 1) Do not post images for textual data. Copy and paste as text 2) Store timestamps as `timestamptz` not `decimal`. 3) Try: `to_timestamp((creation_timestamp *)/1000)::date`

Comment: That should have been: `to_timestamp((creation_timestamp * 1000000000000)/1000)::date`.

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/